# Port forwarding to a hidden service

Tags: configuration, onion-services

For example I have hidden service xxxxx.onion:1234 and I want to forward port 1234 to the clearnet on another server. Can I do it without any socks/http proxy?

So I want to do something like

```
redir --lport=1234 --caddr=xxxxx.onion --cport=1234
```

I don't need to create new hidden service I've already got it.

Answer (score 3):

[Read The !$%# Manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HiddenServicePort)

> **HiddenServicePort VIRTPORT [TARGET]**
>
> Configure a virtual port VIRTPORT for a hidden service. You may use this option multiple times; each time applies to the service using the most recent HiddenServiceDir. By default, this option maps the virtual port to the same port on 127.0.0.1 over TCP. **You may override the target port, address, or both by specifying a target of addr, port, addr:port, or unix:path.** (You can specify an IPv6 target as [addr]:port.) You may also have multiple lines with the same VIRTPORT: when a user connects to that VIRTPORT, one of the TARGETs from those lines will be chosen at random.

e.g.

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/foo/
HiddenServicePort 1234 5.6.7.8:1234
```

Update:

In your updated case (which seems to be the inverse of "I want to forward [...] *to* the clearnet"), you want some non-onion site to display the content of an onion. This will require *at least* some form of proxy to fetch content from the tor network. What you seem to be describing is [Tor2Web](https://tor2web.org/).

Comment: Actually, in case of a *very bad site building*, he will need a HTTPS proxy with CONNECT method to do this: badly designed sites can use multiple host+port combos... But usually - your answer covers it up in full

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make this work using `socat` but I did find a nice new Golang proxy that worked without any issue: https://github.com/willscott/onionproxy.

Answer (score 0):

You need NGinX - or another appropriate to your service - *server* bound to your localhost *and* a socket listener rule **for the very addressed you need**, no proxy is needed as well